# VBA Excel - Application or object oriented error with =HYPERLINK

Tags: excel, hyperlink, vba

I have a problem with a VBA-based hyperlink in Excel 2016. I want to add a "Navigation" sheet in front of all other sheets but I have an issue with "=HYPERLINK". My code is the following:

```
Dim wbBook As workbook

Dim wsActive As Worksheet
Dim wsSheet As Worksheet

Dim lnRow As Long
Dim lnPages As Long
Dim lnCount As Long

Dim temp As Variant

Set wbBook = ActiveWorkbook

wbBook.Sheets.Add(Before:=Worksheets(1)).Name = "Navigation"

Set wsActive = wbBook.ActiveSheet

With wsActive
    .Name = "Navigation"
    With .Range("A1:A1")
        .Value = VBA.Array("Mitarbeiter")
        .Font.Bold = True
    End With
End With

lnRow = 2
lnCount = 1

For Each wsSheet In wbBook.Worksheets
    If wsSheet.Name <> wsActive.Name Then
        wsSheet.Activate
        With wsActive
            Worksheets("Navigation").Cells(lnRow, 1).Formula = _
            "=HYPERLINK(" & Chr(34) & "#" & "'" & wsSheet.Name & "'" & "!A" & lnRow & Chr(34) & ";" & Chr(34) & wsSheet.Name & Chr(34) & ")"      
        End With
        lnRow = lnRow + 1
        lnCount = lnCount + 1
    End If
Next wsSheet
```

The problem I have is that when I add an "=" in front of HYPERLINK, the error "Anwendungs- oder objektorientierter Fehler" (application or object oriented error) pops up. If I run the macro without the "=", the program works but I manually have to add the equation sign in the navigation sheet.

Cheers in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using VBA, why not the VBA capability of Adding Hyperlinks (with `.Hyperlinks.Add`).

You can read about it more on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822490.aspx)

I reduced a the use of `ActiveSheet`, and `Activate`.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestHyperlink()

Dim wbBook As Workbook
Dim wsActive As Worksheet
Dim wsSheet As Worksheet

Dim lnRow As Long
Dim lnPages As Long
Dim lnCount As Long
Dim temp As Variant

Set wbBook = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsActive = wbBook.Sheets.Add(Before:=Worksheets(1))
With wsActive
    .Name = "Navigation"
    With .Range("A1:A1")
        .Value = VBA.Array("Mitarbeiter")
        .Font.Bold = True
    End With
End With

lnRow = 2
lnCount = 1

For Each wsSheet In wbBook.Worksheets
    If wsSheet.Name <> wsActive.Name Then
        With wsSheet
            .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Worksheets("Navigation").Range("A" & lnRow), _
                Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & .Name & "'!" & .Range("A" & lnRow).Address, _
                TextToDisplay:="#" & .Name
        End With
        lnRow = lnRow + 1
        lnCount = lnCount + 1
    End If
Next wsSheet

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply!
I also tried the .Add method, but it didn't work as well, that's why I tried to solve it "manually". When I run your code the following message comes up:
Server busy, the action can't be finished as the other application is busy. Change to... to activate the other application and to solve the problem.

But if I keep on pressing "Wechseln zu...", nothing happens.

I have to mention that I'm running the macro in MS-Project, but it shouldn't be a problem as I'm writing in an excle-file.

Comment: Well yes, this code is part of my VBA in MS Project. I'm exporting data from MS Project via the macro and write it in an Excel file. Everything works fine just the equation sign in front of the HYPERLINK makes some trouble. If I leave the equation sign, the program works but as already mentioned I manually have to add the "=" to get a formula, which is not convenient ;).

Answer (score 0):

Try using a comma to separate the parameters of the formula instead of a semicolon. I think forcing formulae into cells like this ignores localisation.

```
    With wsActive
        Worksheets("Navigation").Cells(lnRow, 1).Formula = _
        "=HYPERLINK(" & Chr(34) & "#" & "'" & wsSheet.Name & "'" & "!A" & lnRow & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & wsSheet.Name & Chr(34) & ")"      
    End With
```

Comment: Unfortunately I need the semicolon as I have a German version of Excel. Otherwise the hyperlink won't work.
That's the equation I need in Excel:
**=HYPERLINK("#'Shee1'!A4";"Sheet1")**

Comment: @Chris  then just replace Formula to FormulaLocal and it should work

Comment: @Shai I changed the code to **Worksheets("Navigation").Cells(lnRow, 1).FormulaLocal = _** but the "Server busy" error still comes up.

Comment: @Chris - I appreciate that you __should__ be using a semicolon - but did you try it with the comma? I've seen several posts recently suggesting there is an issue with using `.Formula` in this way. As @Shai suggests - `.FormulaLocal` is better and should remove the issue. If you're getting "Server Busy" with either of these methods then I'd suggest there is another issue at play here (Using the comma version of your code on my UK machine I had no issue creating links).

Comment: @CLR yes, when I use the comma in connection with .FormulaLocal:
`With wsActive Worksheets("Navigation").Cells(lnRow, 1).FormulaLocal = _
"=HYPERLINK(" & Chr(34) & "#" & "'" & wsSheet.Name & "'" & "!A" & lnRow & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & wsSheet.Name & Chr(34) & ")"
            End With`

 I get the error **"application or object oriented error"**, strange that it's working on your machine.

Comment: @CLR So when I write the hyperlink in a cell and I want to save it right afterwards with `workbook.Save`, the **Server Busy** error comes up. Is it possible that there is a problem with a process in the background such as something in the clipboard or other Office apps? Do I have to add something before I save the written data to the Excel sheet?

Comment: I've not come across that myself but I rarely use `HYPERLINK`. Provided all of the links reference other parts of the same file I can't see why this would happen. Perhaps someone else reading this knows of something though..